# Can Pakistani born person, who became Spanish citizen, be allowed to have a NICOP from Nadra Pakistan?

Tags: spain, pakistani-citizen

Can  Pakistani born person, who became Spanish citizen, be allowed to have a NICOP  (National Identity Card for Overseas Pakistanis) from Nadra Pakistan?.

Answer (score 1):

Pakistan apparently has [dual nationality agreements with 19 countries](http://www.dgip.gov.pk/files/immigration.aspx), not including Spain, which suggests that the person is no longer a citizen of Pakistan.  NICOP is [only available to citizens of Pakistan](https://www.nadra.gov.pk/identity/identity-nicop/), so the answer to your question appears to be *no.*

Comment: It’s not that simple. A Pakistani court has ruled that a Pakistani citizen does not cease to be a citizen unless he has renounced his citizenship while acquiring the other.

Comment: @greatone I would gladly vote for another answer that provided more detail than this answer.

Comment: @greatone, to acquire Spanish citizenship it is necessary to renounce your existing citizenship, with a few exceptions (basically former Spanish colonies and Portugal). Whether Pakistan recognises that renunciation is the key question.

Comment: @PeterTaylor another key question is whether Pakistani citizenship is lost automatically on acquisition of Spanish citizenship (perhaps because there is no dual nationality agreement).  Many countries have laws like that.

Comment: @PeterrTaylor What form does Spain require to prove that the former citizenship has been renounced?

Comment: @MarkJohnson, I haven't done it myself, but I've heard from other British citizens that they had to surrender their passports, which Spain then sent to the UK (and the UK, not recognising a renunciation unless done in a certain way, sent them back on to the holders). But things may have changed since then, and may depend on which bureaucrat deals with the individual case.

Comment: Those are more written rules than anything else of concrete. They really wouldn't treat a Pakistani-British differently than a Spanish-Pakistani or US-Pakistani, so I guess he's clean

Comment: ** The nationals of these countries are not required to renounce their nationality while acquiring Pakistan Citizenship**, not the other way around